# How to calculate inverse log2 ratio of a UCSC wiggle file using perl?

Tags: perl, awk

I have 2 separate files namely A &  B containing same header lines but 2 and 1 column respectively. I want to take inverse log2 of the 2nd column or 1st column in separate files but keep the other description intact. I am having some thing like this.. values in file A $1 and $2 are separated by delimiter **tab**
 **file A**

```
track type=wiggle_0 name=rep1.bar.wig description=GSM1076_rep1.bar.wig graphType=bar  
variableStep chrom=chr1  
12  0.781985  
16  0.810993  
20  0.769601  
24  0.733831
```

**file B**

```
track type=wiggle_0 name=rep1.bar.wig description=GSM1078_rep1.bar.wig graphType=bar
variableStep chrom=chr1  
0.721985  
0.610993  
0.760123  
0.573831
```

I expect an output like this. **file A**

```
track type=wiggle_0 name=rep1.bar.wig description=GSM1076_rep1.bar.wig graphType=bar  
variableStep chrom=chr1  
12  1.7194950944  
16  1.754418585  
20  1.7047982296  
24  1.6630493726  
track type=wiggle_0 name=rep1.bar.wig description=GSM1076_rep1.bar.wig  graphType=bar  
variableStep chrom=chr2
```

**for file B** (in this file values are just copy paste of file A)

```
track type=wiggle_0 name=rep1.bar.wig description=GSM1078_rep1.bar.wig  graphType=bar  
variableStep chrom=chr1   
1.7194950944  
1.754418585  
1.7047982296  
1.6630493726  
track type=wiggle_0 name=rep1.bar.wig description=GSM1078_rep1.bar.wig rep1.bar.wig graphType=bar  
variableStep chrom=chr2
```

Comment: So what is the rule? The 2nd example can't be deduced from the 1st. At least I don't see how.

Comment: I mean 2^$2 or 2**$2

Comment: I see. I'd use a little Perl script for that, but awk probably hurts more ;-)

Comment: @Thomas Kilian, would be great if you could provide that little Perl script

Comment: I'll post the code but I'm unsure about the header lines. The output file A (and B) has `chrom=chr2` as last line. Should that be created extra as variant of the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the Perl version:

```
use strict;
open IN, $ARGV[0];
while (<IN>) {
  chomp;  
  if (/^(.*)[\t ]*(-?\d\.\d*)/) { # format "nn m.mmmmm"
    my $power = 2 ** $2;
    print("$1\t" . $power . "\n");
  } elsif (/^(-?\d\.\d*)/) { # format "m.mmmmm"
    my $power = 2 ** $1;
    print($power . "\n");
  } else { # echo all other stuff
    print;
    print ("\n");
  }
}
close IN;
```

If you run `<file>.pl <datafile>` (replace with appropriate names) it will convert one file so the lines have 2**<2nd value>). It simply echoes the lines that do not match the number pattern.

Comment: perl script is working for the file which has single column ($1) but not for 2 ($1<tab>$2)column. It is missing the first line of header for 2 column file. on the other hand perl script is taking in account only positive (+) value, not the values in negative(-). This will change the outcome of the 2^ value calculation.

Comment: script is working perfectly on 1 column file, but in 2 column file, every thing is fine unless program reaches 100 point in 1st column. it is not calculating the values after reaching that just printing the original values.

Comment: You should state the exact format of your input file. The example has fixed 2 digits. So what?? I changed it so it accepts arbitrary digits before a separator.

Comment: I have large >10 million lines file,which has some header description after every approx. 1 million lines. your new script is adding an extra column "-" in each file type.

Comment: Well, I'm not your coding monkey. Go and find someone you can pay to the 10 million lines >:-(

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and script. I will try, If I could use your perl script some way.

Comment: I have posted the modified perl script, It couldn't have been done without your script.Thanks for providing it.

Answer (score 2):

This awk script does the calculation that you want:

```
awk '/^[0-9.[:space:]]+$/{$NF=sprintf("%.12f", 2^$NF)}1' file
```

This matches lines that contain only digits, periods and any space characters, substituting the value of the last field `$NF` for 2 raised to the power of `$NF`. The format specifier `%.12f` can be modified to give you the required number of decimal places. The `1` at the end is shorthand for `{print}`.

Testing it out on your new files:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9.[:space:]]+$/{$NF=sprintf("%.12f", 2^$NF)}1' A   
track type=wiggle_0 name=rep1.bar.wig description=GSM1076_rep1.bar.wig graphType=bar  
variableStep chrom=chr1  
12 1.719495094445
16 1.754418584953
20 1.704798229573
24 1.663049372620
$ awk '/^[0-9.[:space:]]+$/{$NF=sprintf("%.12f", 2^$NF)}1' B
track type=wiggle_0 name=rep1.bar.wig description=GSM1078_rep1.bar.wig graphType=bar
variableStep chrom=chr1  
1.649449947457
1.527310087388
1.693635012985
1.488470882686
```

Comment: Just tried with awk on my Mac: does not work. Prints `12 1,000000000000` etc.

Comment: @ThomasKilian that will be due to your locale settings (I assume that you use a `,` as a decimal point).

Comment: @TomFenech, I could see awk script is working in your hand, but not with me, It is just printing the original file. I could not figure out what mistake am i making in executing the command? wish I could send you first 1000 lines as attachment. on the other hand original file is huge which has positive, negative as well as NaN values.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the modified little script of @ThomasKilian
>   Thanks to him for providing the framework.

```
use strict;
    open IN, $ARGV[0];
    while (<IN>) {
      chomp;  
      if (/^(\d*)[\t ]*(-?\d\.\d*)/) { # format "nn m.mmmmm"
        my $power = 2 ** $2;
        $power= sprintf("%.12f", $power);
        print("$1\t" . $power . "\n");
      } elsif (/^(-?\d\.\d*)/) { # format "m.mmmmm"
        my $power = 2 ** $1;
        $power= sprintf("%.12f", $power);
        print($power . "\n");
      } else { # echo all other stuff
        print;
        print ("\n");
      }
    }
    close IN;
```